# multiply two complex functions whose limits do not exist

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are complex functions such that 
$$\lim_{z\to 0} f(z) \quad \textrm{and} \quad \lim_{z\to 0} g(z)$$
both do not exist. Is it possible for 
$$\lim_{z\to 0} f(z)g(z)$$
exists? If so, please give an example. If not, please give a proof or logical explanation. Thanks.

Comment: There are many trivial examples ($f(z)=\sin(1/z)$ or anything similar, and $g(z)=1/f(z)$...) surely there's a context?

Comment: Take f(z)=e^(1/z) ,  g(z)=e^(-1/z)  , z0=0

Answer (score 1):

Sure
$$f(z)=\cos(\frac 1 z)$$ and $$g(z)=\frac 1 {\cos (\frac 1 z)}$$